# Determining what AppleScript commands an application responds to

Tags: macos, applescript

Is it possible to ask an OSX application which applescript commands it responds to, and if so, how?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to look at the Dictionary for an application to see all of the classes and commands the application supports. To get to an application's Dictionary in the the Applescript Editor go to `File > Open Dictionary...`. A list of all the applications that the OS knows supports Applescript will appear, but the OS won't catch them all so you can use the Browse button. If an application doesn't support Applescript, then it won't be selectable in the dialog window.

The caveat to this is that there are certain commands that an application is supposed to support but don't, or an application may only support the minimum requirements. These are all very, very simple like `open`, `quit`, etc. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: I feel like I'm going to waste so much time making scripts for the most mundane tasks.

Comment: What do you do if the application isn't scriptable and you need its commands, before taking the GUI scripting approach i.e. how do you list the commands then?