# iTunes Application Loader - automation

Tags: macos, scripting, applescript, app-store-connect

Since recently Apple changed the iTunes Connect interface, and people are required to upload apps with the Application Loader.

That's nice but I need a script for automating my work.

How can an app like App Loader be automated?

I was thinking of something written in AppleScript ... but I don't know what actions it exposes (if any). Found somewhere that I could also do GUI scripting from within AppleScript, but I can't find docs on that.

What I need ... some way to trigger input actions (mouse clicks / keyboard input) and read the text from the various controls displayed.

If that would be possible in Python/Ruby it would be great, but AppleScript is fine.

OS X is version 10.6.4.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Application Loader documentation mentions an altool which can be used for this purpose. (https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf)

***The relevant information:***

> You can use altool, Application Loader’s command-line tool for
>   validating and uploading your application binary files to the App
>   Store.
>
> To validate your build before upload or to automate uploads of valid
>   builds to the App Store, you can include altool in your continuous
>   integration systems. altool is located in the Application
>   Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/Versions/A/Support/
>   folder. (So full path would be
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\
>   Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/Support/altool)
>
> To run altool, specify one of the following at the command-line:
>
> **$ altool --validate-app -f file -u username [-p password]
>   [--output-format xml]**
>
> **$ altool --upload-app -f file -u username [-p
>   password] [--output-format xml]**
>
> Where:
>
> --validate-app Specifies you want to validate the specified application.
>
> --upload-app Specifies you want to upload the specified application.
>
> -f file Specifies the path and filename for the application you are validating or uploading.
>
> -u username Specifies your username (Apple ID).
>
> -p password Specifies your user password.
>
> --output-format [xml | normal] Specifies that you want Application Loader to return output in structured XML format or unstructured text
>   format. By default, Application Loader returns output information in text format.

Comment: Sorry, I know this is an old question, but it still comes up in Google and I'd love for this new information to be available.

Comment: Chad, thanks for adding to it. I moved on to other things and at that time I ended up automating the app loader with Cocoa scripting, as the CLI interface wasn't available. Glad that there is a command line interface now. Cheers,

Comment: Thanks for posting the full path of the `altool`.

Answer (score 2):

In order to see what Applescript commands any application supports, then you need to look at the Dictionary for the application. [From my answer to a similar question posted just the other day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430313/determining-what-applescript-commands-an-application-responds-to):

> To get to an application's Dictionary in the the Applescript Editor go to File > Open Dictionary.... A list of all the applications that the OS knows supports Applescript will appear, but the OS won't catch them all so you can use the Browse button. If an application doesn't support Applescript, then it won't be selectable in the dialog window.
>
> The caveat to this is that there are certain commands that an application is supposed to support but don't, or an application may only support the minimum requirements. These are all very, very simple like open, quit, etc. Your mileage may vary.

Information to start with GUI scripting [can be found on the OS X Automation site](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/uiscripting/index.html). GUI Scripting is a funky way to go, and I don't think you can get the values of onscreen controls, instead only set them. You should only do this if no other avenue works.

If you wish to stick with Python, then you can look at the [py-appscript project](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/py-appscript/index.html), but this is still dependent on Applescript support of the application.

Comment: Thanks Philip ... that py-appscript suggestion was useful.

Unfortunately the app doesn't have a dictionary, so UI scripting is all I have.

However I think I managed to do it. You can get the value of some element with something like ... "get value of text field 1 of row 1..."; and this is useful for error reporting.

Comment: I'm not surprised by the lack of a dictionary. Applescript has, more or less, fallen out of favor with Apple, it seems. They only do implementations in their more public, flagship apps, and even then it could be argued that they are feature-incomplete. In those cases, GUI scripting is really the only way to go. The one real pitfall that I know of (other than the syntax and keeping track of which control you are manipulating) is that unintended alert and dialog windows may (and will) cause the script to error out. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, I already had some issues with unintended alerts / dialog boxes. But to minimize such instances, when the script starts, I first terminate the application to get rid of the previous state. If it can't be terminated normally (like in the case the app asks for confirmation or something) I'm then doing a "kill -9". Starting from scratch on every action sure helps a lot in that regard.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of these commands either one by one or all in one bash script to actually automate your Archive, Extract and Upload process to the AppStore Connect.

**ARCHIVE**

```
xcodebuild -workspace "${APP_NAME}.xcworkspace" -scheme "${APP_NAME}" clean archive -configuration release -sdk iphoneos -archivePath ".build/${TEMP_BUILD}.xcarchive"
```

**EXPORT TO IPA**

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath  ".build/${TEMP_BUILD}.xcarchive" -exportOptionsPlist  "ExportOptions.plist" -exportPath  ".build/${TEMP_BUILD}.ipa"
```

**UPLOAD IPA TO TESTFLIGHT**

```
altool --upload-app -f ".build/${TEMP_BUILD}.ipa/${APP_NAME}.ipa" -u $APP_STORE_USERNAME -p $APP_STORE_PASSWORD
```

> 1) If you don't know what should be your ExportOptions.plist file just
>   take a look [here](https://blog.bitrise.io/new-export-options-plist-in-xcode-9).
>
> 2) To use `altool` from anywhere in the terminal you could add it to your
>   PATH env variable by typing in terminal:
>
> ```
> MacBook-Pro:~ denis$ export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/Support/
> MacBook-Pro:~ denis$ source ~/.bash_profile
> ```