# How to upload apk to google play store via command line

Tags: android, command-line, ant, google-play, apk

Since my application is built and packaged with ant, I also want to automate uploading the generated apk to play store. A command line tool like Apple's ApplicationLoader would be great for this task. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450288/itunes-application-loader-automation);

$ altool --upload-app -f file -u username [-p password] [--output-format xml]

I know an [android-publisher api](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/edits/apks/upload#http-request) and some [api libraries](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/libraries) exists but you need to write your own app to manage the complicated flow. There are some command line [tools](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Automating-Publishing-to-the-Play-Store) for Gradle and Jenkins which are not helpful when using ant.

Is there already a command line tool for uploading to playstore or should I write my own tool by implementing the android-publisher api?

Comment: considering that ant is deprecated and the Android Tools team is focused on Android Studio and gradle. I believe you're out of luck and you probably have 3 options: 1) code your own; 2) clone this https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher and make necessary modifications to work as a standalone cmd line (after all it's just a groovy project) 3) move to the current supported build system (gradle)

Comment: I think having a command line tool is a general issue beyond the automation process you use. Since I could have just been using a bat file. But you are right about the current situation. No support is available about that. Moving to gradle is a big thing for me now so I am thinking about coding my own app. Thanks for your help.