# Applescript for Mac Office 2011

Tags: outlook, applescript

Is there any Applescript available that sends either an URL or array of images as attachment of the mail through Mac Office 2011?

Comment: Have you looked at the Applescript Dictionary for Office 2011 yet?

Comment: I am new to apple script. I don't know how to use the dictionary. It will be helpful if someone gives the applescript that is readily available.

Answer (score 1):

Also see:

MS Outlook 2011 sp1 V14.1.0 changes the apple script dictionary..
http://www.officeformachelp.com/2011/04/microsoft-updates-applescript-dictionary-for-outlook-2011-sp1/

also:

run send all -- forces mail in out box to be  sent right now

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as how Office 2011 is very new, I'd be surprised you'll find ready-made code to use outside of an example script given with Office. [This is where the Dictionary comes in; the Dictionary tells you everything that an application responds to, what objects can be manipulated, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430313/determining-what-applescript-commands-an-application-responds-to) When scripting an application for the first time, the Dictionary will always be the first thing you look at.

What you are asking doesn't seem like it would be too hard figure out even for someone who is new to Applescript.

**UPDATE:** Here is *teh codez* for Entourage 2008. I would imagine that v2011 wouldn't stray too much from this because it is very straightforward:

```
tell application "Microsoft Entourage"
 set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:"New Outgoing Message Subject", recipient:"email@domain.com", content:"Message Body", attachment:{pathToFile1, pathToFile2}}
end tell
--> RESULT: A new message appears in the Outbox with the content placed
```

Comment: @Philip Regan How to add content/source to a existing viewed message in read pane or compose pane?

Comment: @thinkcool: I saw your question earlier, but I don't have Outlook. I have Entourage and I couldn't get your script to work at all. Any conversation about your question should happen at your question, not in the comments of someone else's.